# Connect "computer-database-jpa" Play 2.1 sample application with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm playing with [computer-database-jpa (Java)](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/2.1.x/samples/java/computer-database-jpa) Play Framework 2.1 sample application. Everything works fine when I'm using H2 in memory database but I had problems when I want to connect the application with MySQL.

Some one had the same problem ([Help wanted getting sample app connected to MySQL](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/gIjd3O18TO4/OovsuKr9kGUJ)) but there was no solution.

I've added `mysql-connector` (Build.scala):

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  ....
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```

and edited application.conf:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://password:user@localhost/my-database"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I start the applications and apply 1.sql (evolution script) I get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence company_seq
start with 1000' at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution - https://github.com/opensas/openshift-play2-computerdb.

Syntax used in evolution scripts isn't conform with `MySQL`:

> ### List of changes needed to port computer-database sample app from H2 to mysql
>
> #### conf/evolutions/default/1.sql
>
> - added engine=innodb, to enable referential integrity
> - replaced sequences with autoincrement for id fields
> - replaced 'SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY' command with 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS'
> - replaced timestamp fields with datetime
>
> #### conf/evolutions/default/2.sql
>
> - splitted the computer data between 2.sql and 3.sql file (avoid bug in evolutions running on mysql)
>
> #### models/Models.scala
>
> - removed 'nulls last' from Computer.list sql query
> - modified Computer.insert to skip id field (because is auto-assigned by mysql)

Because I was playing with `Java` and not `Scala` version I'd to change `Company.java` and `Computer.java` files. I've added `@GeneratedValue` annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;
```

Here you can find modified evolution scripts: https://github.com/opensas/openshift-play2-computerdb/tree/master/conf/evolutions/default

Comment: I just had the same problem. Looks like this behaviour isn't documented in the play! framework documentation. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I had the same issue as I was using
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "device_gen")
Which I changed to 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)