# ebean generates non-mysql-compatible evolutions

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I was developing on my machine with Postgres and everything was nice.

But after moving to the server with MySQL and provided in **application.conf** with:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/app"
db.default.user=app
db.default.password={PASSWORD_GOES_HERE}
```

ebean still keeps generating non-mysql-compatible evolutions with "**create sequence**" and "**add constraint fk_**".

Any ideas on how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider this article about similar problem while using Play!Framework Ebean and MySQL database [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783586/connect-computer-database-jpa-play-2-1-sample-application-with-mysql).

I think you must modified manually the incompatible SQL syntax on the generated evolution script with MySQL compatible one.